# shapes with the :after tag

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am wondering if it is possible to make shapes with no html code, only with css.

Example:
I have a menu :
html

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For each menu item I want to add a triangle at the end of it without adding other html tags to the code and align them with the text.

Is this possible with the CSS selector `:after` ?

Comment: have you tried it yet?  i'm pretty sure it is possible.

Comment: Check out this http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ , http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the triangle aligned with the text and with the `:after` selector this is the solution.

([João Mosmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1390477/joao-mosmann) put me on the right path with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20356840/1811992))

HTML :

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
li{
    position:relative;
}
li:after{
    content:" ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Md6fb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Check here a example.

http://jsfiddle.net/m4fkW/

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
li:after{
    content:" ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
}
```

Comment: just what I wan looking for is it possible to align the triangles with the text?

Answer (score 1):

```
li:after { content: url(img.jpg); }
```

Comment: thx but I wanted prefer adding a css shape here with no image

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
ul li:after{url('Traingle url goes here')}
```

Comment: Same as Tiago, I prefer adding it only with css and no image

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with pure CSS.

Please look at [this link](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) for a full list of shapes.

But the triangles are here:

```
#triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}

#triangle-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid red;
}

#triangle-left {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid red;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

#triangle-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 100px solid red;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

and more on the website.

Comment: I can make shapes, all I want to know is if it is possible add them with the :after selector

Comment: Yes, just use `:after` and make sure you use `content:'';'` @chadocat